# Cakephp 3.x join with OR condition always result as AND

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Code

```
$query = $this->Client->find()
                ->hydrate(false)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->page($page)
                ->select(['Client.id','Client.achternaam','Client.Voornaam','clvsstatus.clientopnamestatus_id',
                    'clstatus.naam','afd.afdeling_naam','clsrtopn.naam'])
                ->join([
                    'clvsstatus' => [
                        'table' => 'client_vs_clientsoortstatus',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => [
                            'clvsstatus.client_id = client.id',
                            'clvsstatus.datum_van <='=>'2016-10-21',
                            'clvsstatus.datum_tot >='=>'2016-10-21',
                            **'OR' => ['clvsstatus.datum_tot'=>'0000-00-00']**                            
                        ],
                    ],
                    'clstatus' => [
                        'table' => 'clientsoortstatus',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'clstatus.id = clvsstatus.clientopnamestatus_id',
                    ],
                    'clvsafdeling' => [
                        'table' => 'client_vs_afdeling',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => [
                            'clvsafdeling.client_id = clvsstatus.client_id',
                            'clvsafdeling.client_id = clvsstatus.client_id '
                            ],
                    ],                    
                    'afd' => [
                        'table' => 'afdeling',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'afd.afdeling_afdelingid = clvsafdeling.afdeling_id',
                    ],                    
                    'clvssrtopn' => [
                        'table' => 'client_vs_clientsoortopname',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'clvssrtopn.client_id = client.id',
                    ],                    
                    'clsrtopn' => [
                        'table' => 'clientsoortopname',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'clsrtopn.id = clvssrtopn.clientopnamesoort_id',
                    ]                                                     

                ]) ;
```

Resulting SQL

```
SELECT 
  Client.id AS `Client__id`, 
  Client.achternaam AS `Client__achternaam`, 
  Client.Voornaam AS `Client__Voornaam`, 
  clvsstatus.clientopnamestatus_id AS `clvsstatus__clientopnamestatus_id`, 
  clstatus.naam AS `clstatus__naam`, 
  afd.afdeling_naam AS `afd__afdeling_naam`, 
  clsrtopn.naam AS `clsrtopn__naam` 
FROM 
  client Client 
  INNER JOIN client_vs_clientsoortstatus clvsstatus ON (
    clvsstatus.client_id = client.id 
    AND clvsstatus.datum_van <= '2016-10-21' 
    AND clvsstatus.datum_tot >= '2016-10-21' 
    **AND clvsstatus.datum_tot = '0000-00-00'**
  ) 
  INNER JOIN clientsoortstatus clstatus ON clstatus.id = clvsstatus.clientopnamestatus_id 
  INNER JOIN client_vs_afdeling clvsafdeling ON (
    clvsafdeling.client_id = clvsstatus.client_id 
    AND clvsafdeling.client_id = clvsstatus.client_id
  ) 
  INNER JOIN afdeling afd ON afd.afdeling_afdelingid = clvsafdeling.afdeling_id 
  INNER JOIN client_vs_clientsoortopname clvssrtopn ON clvssrtopn.client_id = client.id 
  INNER JOIN clientsoortopname clsrtopn ON clsrtopn.id = clvssrtopn.clientopnamesoort_id 
LIMIT 
  15 OFFSET 0
```

COMMENT :
As you see in the above code and resulting SQL even when explicitly ask for an OR condition cake always makes it AND, can anyone help with this thnxs

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the conditions on your first join to the following:

```
    'conditions' => [
        'clvsstatus.client_id = client.id',
        'OR' => [
            'clvsstatus.datum_tot'=>'0000-00-00',
            'AND' => [
                'clvsstatus.datum_van <='=>'2016-10-21',
                'clvsstatus.datum_tot >='=>'2016-10-21',
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: To clarify why, it will "OR" together everything inside that array, and "AND" together everything in the main array (or anything with the AND key). So, in your original example, it was going to AND together four conditions, the last of which would be the result of ORing only a single thing (which is just the thing; that is OR[x] is just x). Hope this helps some, and doesn't just muddy the waters for you!

Comment: @GregSchmidt yep, that's basically it. Thanks for elaborating! I was in a hurry and couldn't do it myself.